# How to raise exception when function call is missing an argument in Python

Tags: python, exception

If I have the function

```
def my_function(a,b,c):
```

and when the user calls the function, they omit the last argument

```
print(my_function(a,b))
```

what exception should I raise?

Comment: Do you want to raise an exception or catch it? Because Python already raises a `TypeError` for you in that case.

Comment: I have a default argument for c that the function should use if the user omits the last argument when calling. I need to raise an exception in the case that the user omits the argument, so the function uses my default argument.

Comment: So what you want to do is use a default argument instead of raising an exception? You meant 'what exception should I catch'?

Comment: The function will use the default argument, you don't need to raise an exception.

Comment: The default argument is just in case the last argument is missing. An if statement to use the default argument also works.

Comment: Please provide an example to illustrate what you are envisioning inside the function  here.

Comment: @OlivierMelançon: Because I don't think it accurately reflects the questioner's thoughts. It sounds like the questioner expected to manually raise an exception somewhere to handle this situation.

Comment: @OlivierMelançon: I don't think that's actually clear. There's no indication that they expected there to be an exception at all unless they raised one themselves.

Comment: @user2357112 is right in saying that I am expected to manually raise an exception to be able to use the default argument, and print a message stating that a default is being used due to the user error.

Comment: @JessicaMartinez and you are aware that Python Raises one already for missing arguments?

Comment: I know this is an old thread, but for anyone who gets here late like I did, here is the concrete example that lead me here.

I have function that defaults an optional parameter to None.   The necessity of the parameter being specified depends on other input parameters.  It is convenient, therefore, to only check if is specified if/when it is truly needed.  Use of the default parameter allows callers to not provided it in situation where it is not needed.  In my particular case, the immediate caller does not need to know the logic of when the parameter is or is not required.

Comment: In my case, I am leaning toward raising a ValueError as None is an invalid value when the parameter is needed.

Answer (score 5):

As others have mentioned, Python will raise a `TypeError` if a function is called with an incorrect number of statically declared arguments. It seems there is no practical reason to override this behavior to raise your own custom error message since Python's:

```
TypeError: f() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given
```

is quite telling.

However, if you want to do this, and perhaps optionally allow a second argument, you can use `*args`.

```
def my_function(a, *args):
    b = None
    if len(args) > 1:
        raise TypeError("More than 2 arguments not allowed.")
    elif args:
        b = args[0]

    # do something with a and possibly b.
```

**Edit:** The other answer suggesting a default keyword argument is more appropriate given new additional details in OP’s comment.

Answer (score 4):

After discussion in the comment, it seems that what you want to do is *catch* an exception to pass a default argument if one was missing.

First of all, Python will already raise a `TypeError` if an argument is missing.

But you do not need to *catch* it to have default arguments since Python already provides a way to do this.

```
def my_function(a, b, c=0):
    pass

my_function(1, 2, 3) # This works fine
my_function(1, 2) # This works as well an used 0 as default argument for c
```